# How to make a POST API call in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react program for front-end which makes a api call when a form is submitted, I want the contents of the form to be sent in JSON format

Back-end code works fine, back-end is written in python and it works fine when I test using postman.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

class MainCon extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            systemId: "",
            password: "",
            systemType: "",
            ip: "",
            portNumber: "",
            sourceAddressTon: "",
            sourceAddressNpi: "",
            sourceAddress: "",
            destinationAddressTon: "",
            destinationAddressNpi: "",
            destinationAddress: "",
            registeredDelivery: "",
            dataCoding: "",
            shortMessage: "",

            id: "",

            //isFriendly: false,
            messageMethod: "",
            //favColor: "blue"
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        //const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        // type === "checkbox" ? this.setState({ [name]: checked }) : this.setState({ [name]: value })

        const { name, value } = event.target
        this.setState({ [name]: value })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.target);
        console.log(event.target);
        let object = {}
        for (const [key, value] of data.entries()) {
            object[key] = value
        }

        /*
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(object),
        };

        const request = new Request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/add_message', options);
        const response = fetch(response);
        const status = response.status;

        if (status === 201) {
            this.fetchAll()
        }



        */
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/add_message/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(object),
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="systemId">System ID</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.systemId}
                    name="systemId"
                    placeholder="System ID"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="systemType">System Type:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.systemType}
                    name="systemType"
                    placeholder="System Type"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="ip">IP:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.ip}
                    name="ip"
                    placeholder="IP"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="portNumber">Port Number:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.portNumber}
                    name="portNumber"
                    placeholder="Port Number"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="sourceAddressTon">Source Address Ton:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.sourceAddressTon}
                    name="sourceAddressTon"
                    placeholder="Source Address Ton"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="sourceAddressNpi">Source Address Npi:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.sourceAddressNpi}
                    name="sourceAddressNpi"
                    placeholder="Source Address Npi"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="sourceAddress">Source Address:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.sourceAddress}
                    name="sourceAddress"
                    placeholder="Source Address"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="destinationAddressTon">Destination Address Ton:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.destinationAddressTon}
                    name="destinationAddressTon"
                    placeholder="Destination Address Ton"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="destinationAddressNpi">Destination Address Npi:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.destinationAddressNpi}
                    name="destinationAddressNpi"
                    placeholder="Destination Address Npi"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="destinationAddress">Destination Address:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.destinationAddress}
                    name="destinationAddress"
                    placeholder="Destination Address"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="registeredDelivery">Registered Delivery:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.registeredDelivery}
                    name="registeredDelivery"
                    placeholder="Registered Delivery"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="dataCoding">Data Coding:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.dataCoding}
                    name="dataCoding"
                    placeholder="Data Coding"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="messageMethod"
                        value="randomMessage"
                        checked={this.state.messageMethod === "randomMessage"}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    /> Random Message
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="messageMethod"
                        value="customMessage"
                        checked={this.state.messageMethod === "customMessage"}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    /> Custom Message
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="shortMessage">Short Message:</label>
                <textarea
                    //className="hideDontTakeUpSpace"
                    value={this.state.shortMessage}
                    name="shortMessage"
                    placeholder="Short Message"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br />
                {/* Formik */}
                {/**
                <label>Favorite Color:</label>
                <select
                    value={this.state.favColor}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="favColor"
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="green">Green</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                </select>
                */}
                {/*<h1>{this.state.systemId} {this.state.password}</h1>*/}
                <h2>Type of message: {this.state.messageMethod}</h2>
                {/*<h2>Your favorite color is {this.state.favColor}</h2>*/}
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}


export default MainCon
```

This is the server side python code

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from jsonDemoNew import getMemberNew
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api/add_message', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.json
        print request
        print content
        return jsonify({"Number of messages sent": 123, "Printed status" : 1})
    return "Not POST request"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I think there is some problem with the headers I am including

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` prints?

Comment: Nothing is getting printed

Comment: Just remove and `event.target` and check.

Comment: Still nothing..

Comment: POst complete form, and check if server is running.

Comment: Full code has been added, and server is up and running, and the request make through postman is working as it should

Comment: Why don't you use state to built data object for your API request?

Comment: How do I do that? I am sorry I am new to react

Comment: Your code is working fine, you can check this `console.log(object)`, object is getting created and printed correctly. Issue is in your API only. Check server is running on correct port.

Comment: Check the API URL, I think last `/` is not needed.

Comment: Also check this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch, and try to write `.then` & `.catch` logic and check where your code goes.

Comment: can you please check it, i have included server side code as well

Comment: Try this - `const response = fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/add_message',{...})` Notice I have removed last `/` from URL. And then `console.log(response)`

Answer (score -2):

I personally prefer to use axios to make POST requests.

```
    npm install axios --save
```

Just like on postman:

1. Select the method ('post' in that case)
2. Select the url ('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/add_message/')
3. Send theData in "json form" like:

   {
       "data": "oktay"
   }

And it's done:

```
const axios = require('axios');     

const postIt = (theData) => {     
                axios({
                    method: 'post', // THERE GOES THE METHOD
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/add_message/', // THERE GOES THE URL
                    headers: {},
                    data: theData
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                        console.log("The response of the server: "+response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                     // handle error
                     console.log(error);
                })
                .finally(function () {
                        // always executed
                });

             }
postIt({
  "data" : "oktay"
});
```